# Use ECS repository image as build image in CircleCI

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, circleci, amazon-ecs

I have been using my Docker-hub account till now in CircleCI, and now for some reason I'm trying to use my ECR repository image in the same place as build image in CircleCI (2.0)

But I see ECR doesn't support public images. So I can't mention my image as below as I did for Dockerhub image,

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working-directory: ~/tmp
    docker:
        - image: <dockerhub-name>/<image>
```

as,

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working-directory: ~/tmp
    docker:
        - image: aws-id.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/image
```

It will throw error,

```
no basic auth credentials
```

In a straight forward operation it needs to get authenticated via command,

```
aws ecr get-login --region <region-name>
```

and then running,

```
docker login -u AWS -p <password> -e none https://aws-id.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

I tried putting this commands in **Pre-dependency commands** section of CircleCI plan settings and didn't work.

Ideas?

Comment: Did you check this https://circleci.com/blog/circleci-aws-ecrecs/ and this https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/continuous-deployment-with-aws-ec2-container-service/

Comment: Its's actually the deploy to docker part they explain everywhere. Not any mention to the build image as ecs repo image.

Comment: You are looking to pull the mage right? After your login command pull the image using the pull command

Comment: That I would I have done on a straight forward shell. It's different with CircleCI config.

Answer (score 1):

What "Pre-dependency commands"? That sounds like you're referring to configuration structure from CircleCI 1.0, which you don't seem to be using.

Because of the way AWS requires you to authenticate with ECR, I wouldn't use an image from there with the `docker` executor. Either use some random image, and then use `setup_remote_docker` or use the `machine` executor.

[This doc](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/building-docker-images/#overview) shows the former, and [this one](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/executor-types/#machine-executor-overview) covers the latter.